# Google AppScript does not fire onclick for html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Google Appscript does not fire onclick for HTML. I am writing a function on Google sheet to show a dialog which has a button. On click of a button, an associated function must get fired. For now, it is a dummy which changes the text of paragraph. I have also embedded an alert message but it does not get fired.

```
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = '....';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    
  function CheckExecute() {
    Browser.msgBox("Hello World!");
    document.getElementById('folderselected').innerHTML = '<b>Folder Id is:</b>';'



  }


  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   
    <p id='result'></p>
    <p id='folderselected'>This is check area again</p>
    <button onclick="CheckExecute();">Click me</button>
    <p id='folderselected1'>This is check area 2</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting Error Browswer is not defined.

Switched to alert and now it works..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  <script>
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = '....';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    
  function CheckExecute() {
    alert("Hello World!");
    document.getElementById('folderselected').innerHTML = '<b>Folder Id is:</b>';
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   
    <p id='result'></p>
    <p id='folderselected'>This is check area again</p>
    <button onclick="CheckExecute();">Click me</button>
    <p id='folderselected1'>This is check area 2</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to spend some time learning how to use console to debug html